# Scrolling through an array of images,

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I was making an image gallery and I ran into this problem, when I scroll right a few times and then scroll left, the last image is displayed twice, and the current image number[indicator] does not match the index of the item in the array, where have I screwed up? Any explanation on why this is happening will be greatly appreciated as well.

```js
let names = ["imageone.jpg", "imagetwo.jpg", "imagethree.jpg", "imagefour.jpg", "imagefive.jpg", "imagesix.jpg", "imageseven.jpg", "imageeight.jpg", "imagenine.jpg"];

let imageContainer = document.querySelector("#screenShotGallery img");
let indicator = document.querySelector("#indicator");
let left = document.querySelector("#left");
let right = document.querySelector("#right");
let current = 0;

function rightScroll() {
  console.log(names[current++], current)
  indicator.textContent = current;
  if (current >= names.length) {
    current = 0
  }

}

right.addEventListener("click", rightScroll);

function leftScroll() {
  // console.log(names[current--],current) this line produces even worse results
  console.log(names[current = current - 1], current)
  indicator.textContent = current;

  if (current <= 0) {
    current = names.length - 1;
    indicator.textContent = current;
  }

}

left.addEventListener("click", leftScroll);
```

```css
.screenShots {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

#screenShotsIntro {
  text-align: center;
}

#screenShotGallery {
  height: 550px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

#left {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 0%;
  left: 45%;
}

#right {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 0%;
  right: 45%;
}

#right:hover,
#left:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 1px 2px gray;
}

#indicator {
  height: 23px;
  width: 25px;
  background: gainsboro;
  position: absolute;
  left: 49%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 23px;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
```

```html
<div id="screenShotGallery">

  <div id=" controls">
    <div id="indicator"></div>
    <div id="left">left</div>
    <div id="right">right</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The array Index is from 0 to 8 and the length of Array is 9. Thats why get error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this.
Also, keep in mind that an array starts from 0 so the length of your array is 9 but that means 0-8 not 1-9. So if you want to target an element of the array using the `current` variable, decrease it by 1 like this `names[current - 1]`. This way the first element of the array will be the equivalent of 1 in your indicator box.

```js
let names = ["imageone.jpg", "imagetwo.jpg", "imagethree.jpg", "imagefour.jpg", "imagefive.jpg", "imagesix.jpg", "imageseven.jpg", "imageeight.jpg", "imagenine.jpg"];

let imageContainer = document.querySelector("#screenShotGallery img");
let indicator = document.querySelector("#indicator");
let left = document.querySelector("#left");
let right = document.querySelector("#right");
let current = 0;

function rightScroll() {
  current++;

  if (current > names.length) {
    current = 1;
  }
  indicator.textContent = current;
}

function leftScroll() {
  current--;

  if (current === 0) {
    current = names.length;
  }
  indicator.textContent = current;
}

left.addEventListener("click", leftScroll);
right.addEventListener("click", rightScroll);
```

```css
.screenShots {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

#screenShotsIntro {
  text-align: center;
}

#screenShotGallery {
  height: 550px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

#left {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 0%;
  left: 45%;
}

#right {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 0%;
  right: 45%;
}

#right:hover,
#left:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 1px 2px gray;
}

#indicator {
  height: 23px;
  width: 25px;
  background: gainsboro;
  position: absolute;
  left: 49%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 23px;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
```

```html
<div id="screenShotGallery">

  <div id=" controls">
    <div id="indicator"></div>
    <div id="left">left</div>
    <div id="right">right</div>
  </div>
</div>
```